# Dropdown list to filter using query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have fed my django database some information on stock prices, and the result of machine learnt code that displays 100 if a pattern is formed and 0 if it isn't. I have rendered out just the essential stock prices to my html page, and now want to add a dropdown menu with pattern names which filters and present the stocks that hv met the condition i.e. =100. Since the pattern data is not available on the html, I tried working with query function in the views.py to render back the results
[image: This is the screenshot of my html page that currently shows only 7 columns out of the 80 I hv in the database]

```
scan = Stock.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'scanner/litescan.html', {'scan':scan})
```

That is my current code that renders out the entire stock data.

I tried to work with the context variable but that didn't seem to workout (the page loaded without data). Or maybe I couldn't render it to the html properly. Following is my attempt:

```
def scan(request):
    scan = Stock.objects.all()
    marubozu = Stock.objects.filter(Marubozu=100)

    context = {'All':scan, 'Marubozu':marubozu
    }

    return render(request, 'scanner/scan.html', context)
```

Little help will be dearly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The context is a dictionary, mapping template variable names to Python objects.

`marubozu` and `scan` are available in templates using `Marubozu` and `All` respectively not by `scan`.

change `{% for i in scan %}` to `{% for i in All %}`

Comment: The context was added later when I tried to put the dropdown list; a failed attempt. I hv edited in my previous code that renders the entire stock data.